# JSONObject vs JARRAY getting array length

Tags: java, android, json

I have a JSONObject that I pass to a method to get processed into `ArrayLists`.

```
{
    "set0" :
    {
        "title" : "Do you win?",
        "answer" : "1",
        "imgUrl" : "imag",
        "id" : "1"
    },
    "set1" :
    {
        "title" : "Did you loose?",
        "answer" : "1",
        "imgUrl" : "imag",
        "id" : "2"
     }
}
```

The method is structured like this:

```
questions(JSONObject result){

    // initialization
    for(int i=0;i < result.length();i++){
        question_list.add(result.getJSONObject("set"+i).getString("title"));
        answer_list.add(result.getJSONObject("set"+i).getString("answer"));
        img_list.add(result.getJSONObject("set"+i).getString("imgUrl"));
        question_batch.add(result.getJSONObject("set"+i).getInt("id"));
    }
    // rest of code
}
```

I normally see the jsonarray being used for the loop condition and not the jsonobject itself, when my jsonobject gets bigger but in the same structure as posted above will `result.length()` start to yield a wrong result and is this an incorrect implementation for someone who will want to iterate through their jsonobject?

Comment: It looks like your data should be stored as a JSONArray, rather than a JSONObject since it represents a list of multiple data objects that are of the same type, rather than just a single data object.

Comment: So you would advise to pass a JSONArray than object to the method?

Comment: Try to use GSON instead of own parsing. Its faster and easy to implement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if your implementation is "incorrect", but this is how I generally iterate through JSON.

```
int i = 0;
boolean continue = true;
while (continue){
    if (result.has("set" + i){

    JSONObject set = result.get("set" + i.toString());

    if (set.has("title"){
        question_list.add(set.getString("title");
    }
    if (set.has("answer"){
        answer_list.add(set.getString("answer");
    }
    if (set.has("imgUrl"){
        image_list.add(set.getString("imgUrl");
    }
    if (set.has("id"){
        question_batch.add(set.getInt("id");
    }

    i++;

    }else{
        continue = false;
    }
}
```

This is a little more efficient because you don't have to create a new JSON object everytime you want to pull data out.
Also I would make a new class to handle the JSON objects, and make the array list of that type, so you only have to add one object for each iteration.  This way, you can be sure that your questions/answers/imageURLs/id's are all kept together.  Like this:

```
JSONObject set = result.get("set" + i.toString());

QuestionObject newQuestion = new QuestionObject();

if (set.has("title"){
    newQuestion.setTitle(result.getString("title");
}
if (set.has("answer"){
    newQuestion.setAnswer(result.getString("answer");
}
if (set.has("imgUrl"){
    newQuestion.setImageURL(result.getString("imgUrl");
}
if (set.has("id"){
    newQuestion.setID(result.getInt("id");
}

questionList.add(newQuestion);
```

Also, in case you didn't notice, you can directly parse integers using `json.getInt()` for your "id" field instead of string.

Comment: Yes i used that in my actual code for parsing Int, just a typo I made here, thanks for pointing it out though

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look to Jackson also. That is also quite straightforward, and your code might benefit from using it.